# Android Navigation Component: Fragments are not visible in drop down list when adding destination from nav_graph.xml

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, navigation-architecture

When I am trying to add a destination when clicking [image]
"New destination"  button, from the dropdown list I am not able to see any fragments which are already there in my project.

I also face this issue when I am trying to add a blank fragment by clicking "Create a blank destination" option from the drop down.

I tried restarting the IDE, and this [Android Navigation Component Not Displaying Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063670/android-navigation-component-not-displaying-fragment) but it doesn't resolve my issue.

Navigation dependency: implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02"

My project is already migrated to AndroidX.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Gradle dependency:

```
def nav_version = "1.0.0-rc02"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
```

Comment: try rebuild the project.

Comment: Sounds like you should file an [issue against the Navigation Editor](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=404706) with a project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Can you share your gradle with the dependency list?

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf edited the question.

Comment: I think I am using wrong dependency

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, I created a new fresh android project to check if the problem is related to IDE or not. Able to create destinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Just use these dependencies.

```
//Android Navigation Architecture
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0-alpha05"
```

Comment: adding the navigation-fragment dependency did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved it by simply checking the superior build-gradle for the kotlin version, it may be the case if you recently updated your kotlin plugin but didnt update your code.

So in android studio in project navigation bar(ANDROID): **Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(project) -> look for buildscript - ext and update "kotlin_version" for your kotlin plugin version (this can be checked in tools -> kotlin -> Configure kotlin plugin updates)**

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same problem, I was using older library version(`1.0.0-alpha05`)

But as soon as I switched to

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0"
```

Other fragments started showing up!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this issue even with version 2.2.1. I have solved this by adding the fragment in the XML code. Then I am able to add actions from the visual editor.

Example:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:name="com.example.test.ui.test.TestFragment"
    android:label="Test Label"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Fragments don't show up in the graph because classes haven't been made for them. After calling onViewCreate within a class, while returning correct inflater they show up in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Just I built and Run the project once. Then Fragments appeared as destinations in the Fragments List in NavGraph.