# Fragments are not displaying in Android Navigation component

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-navigation-editor

Am new with this architecture and am trying to add multiple fragments in the **Android Navigation component** but the **Fragments**
 are not visible in the list.

[image]

As you can see, The host is the only one available.

I also had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063670/android-navigation-component-not-displaying-fragment), but it didn't help me out.

Now, these are the dependencies am using from the documentation :

```
def nav_version = "2.1.0-beta02"
    def nav_version_ktx = "2.1.0-beta02"

     // Java
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version_ktx"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version_ktx"
```

and this :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Then my fragment is as follows :

```
class BlankFragment2 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false)
    }


}
```

and it's **xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".BlankFragment2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The version of my android studio is **3.4.2**

What could be the reason to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the version 2.1.0-alpha02 and have no problems.
Try to change your nav_version_ktx and nav_version

Also this a sample on my [github](https://github.com/matteopasotti/navigation-sample), just in case you want to check something. But i think it's a problem of version

Comment: Ok , let me implement it , but mm seeing you used `Androidx`, does this mean it's a must ?

Comment: Well, I got the solution, I migrated all my project to `androidx` and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the solution, I just migrated my app to use `Androidx`, this made the graph work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your nav graph add "tools:layout="@layout/fragment_your_layout"

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/home2Fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newProfileContentFragment"
        android:name="com.adidas.app.profile2.NewProfileContentFragment"
        android:label="NewProfileContentFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_your_layout"
        />

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have `NavigationComponent` dependency in your `build.gradle.`

```
 ext.navigation_version = "2.3.5"

 // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$navigation_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigation_version"
```