# NO FRAGMENTS found in the NAVIGATION EDITOR

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, google-developers-console

[Navigation Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEnJP.png)

Though there are fragments present in the layout directory, none of it shows up in the navigation editor, except main activity.

p.s: I've also tried Invalidate Caches and Restart but didn't work.

Somebody please help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue here: [Fragments are not displaying in Android Navigation component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271498/fragments-are-not-displaying-in-android-navigation-component) .

Without seeing any code like your dependencies or your fragments it is hard to deduce. If you are not already using the Androidx libraries you could try migrating to those and seeing if that helps.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but things worked as I created a new Project and copied the code there. Thank you anyways!